# REGEX: Select only the first word at the beginning of each line that contain the word HTML

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to select the first word at the beginning of each line that contain the word `HTML`.

For example:

`I go home now.html" and then`

`Take me with you nowhtml" and then`

`My book is great.`

The regex must select the words `I` (from the first line) and `Take` (from the second line)

I made a regex, but it selects the first word from any line, not just those that have HTML:

SEARCH: `^\b(?!html\b)\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find what: `^\w+(?=.+html)`
- Search mode: Regular expression